# Create a TriggeredSend Definition Fatal error: Call to undefined method WSSESoap::addOAuth() in /ET_Client.php on line 165

Tags: soap-api, oauth2, php, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to set of a TriggeredSend definition. After a lot of playing around I got the system to load the ExactTargetWSDL.xml. Now I've got this error showing up, and i'm not sure why.

```
Create a TriggeredSend Definition Fatal error: Call to undefined method WSSESoap::addOAuth() in ET_Client.php on line 165
```

I'm guessing I'm missing some sort of dependency, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was using a different version of soap-wsse.php. The version in the Fuel package has an added `addOauth` method that the version I had didn't. I replaced it with the new one, and all is fine.